# Memory leak: CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData

Tags: ios

I make use of the UIImage+Resize library to resize my images directly after taking them.

I do get a memory leak with the following code:

```
CGContextDrawImage(UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext(), CGRectMake(0, 0, srcSize.width, srcSize.height), imgRef);
UIImage* resizedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData memory leak in Instruments.

I tried adding it into a @autoreleasepool as per other StackOverflow posts.

Comment: All `CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData` means is that the thing you're leaking is the image, and this is where you created the image. It all depends on what you do with `resizedImage` elsewhere. Instruments doesn't tell you where your mistake is. It tells you where memory is allocated.

Comment: Have you found what's wrong with your code?  I have the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

**Note**: You've probably have already fixed your problem, this answer for future readers having the same problem.

I've figured out what's going on my own implementation (video analysis with GPUImage).

I needed to add an `autoreleasepool` closure around the call to `CGBitmapContextCreateImage` caller (it also calls `CGDataProviderCreateWithCopyOfData`).

```
    func run() {
        while (parent != nil) {
            if semaphore.acquireSemaphore(5000) {
                autoreleasepool { // Without this I was leaking images until crash.
                    parent?.analyseImage(self.sampleBuffer!, lineFinder:finder) //This calls CGBitmapContextCreateImage
                }
            }
        }
        thread = nil
    }
```